# How to make a UITextView detect the click on table cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I am working on a project and one of the table views the text for it is a UITextView, but on the other one is a UILabel. The UILabel detects the click from the user as a click on the table cell, but the UITextView doesn't. Why is this happening? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: have you checked that `UITextView`  `isUserInteraction` enabled?

Comment: Is your `UITextView` `editable`?

Comment: Check if any other view is covering the `textView`. Also, check if you've given proper constraints to the `textView`.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Tapping in a `UITextView` will start editing that text view. What would you want your code to do if not that?

Comment: I want it to detect the click, so when I click it the cell to be selected

Comment: your view is inside the cell and when you click the cell your tableview cell should be selected is that way you want  ?

Answer (score 1):

Try that

```
yourTextView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myTargetFunction), for: .touchDown)
@objc func myTargetFunction(textField: UITextView) {
      print("myTargetFunction")
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the isSelectable property of your textView is true.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, the cell view and text view are both scrow views and always will have conflict, so I need to uncheck the UserInteractions and Multiple Touch of the text view, booth set to false

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with both being scroll views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your question whether you're talking about selection on the `UITableView` row or the `UITextView`/`UILabel` itself.

If you're trying to set up a gesture recognizer on the `UILabel` or `UITextView`, I'm wondering if that's necessary or if you could just use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in your view controller.

e.g.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    yourMethodHere(for: cell)
  }
```

Then you'd define in `yourMethodHere()` what behavior you want to happen when the cell is selected.